# Pandas: combine resampling and group by. How do I average values within same groups before summing them up in a time bin?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, datetimeindex

I have tabular data (described by col1, col2,...) associated to a Timestamp and a custom made Group. Example:

```
           Group  Col1  Col2  Col3
Time
2020-05-18     A    10    20    30
2020-05-18     B    10    20    30
2020-05-18     C    10    20    30
2020-05-19     A    10    20    30
2020-05-19     B    10    20    30
2020-05-19     C    10    20    30
2020-05-20     A    10    20    30
2020-05-20     B    10    20    30
2020-05-20     C    10    20    30
2020-05-21     A    10    20    30
2020-05-21     B    10    20    30
2020-05-21     C    10    20    30
```

This dataframe can be generated by:

```py
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"Time": ["2020-05-18", "2020-05-18", "2020-05-18", "2020-05-19", "2020-05-19", "2020-05-19", "2020-05-20", "2020-05-20", "2020-05-20", "2020-05-21", "2020-05-21", "2020-05-21"], "Group": ["A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"], "Col1": 12*[10], "Col2": 12*[20], "Col3": 12*[30]})
dataframe["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe["Time"])
dataframe = dataframe.set_index("Time")
```

I would like to create time bins (like with resample function), average values WITHIN the same group, and  THEN sum them up within the same time bin.
But if I write `dataframe.resample("2D").sum()`, values will be direclty summed up over all the groups without first being averaged in the same group. Like this:

```
            Col1  Col2  Col3
Time
2020-05-18    60   120   180
2020-05-20    60   120   180
```

But what I need is to average values belonging to the same group BEFORE summing them up. In this case the desired output would be:

```
            Col1  Col2  Col3
Time
2020-05-18    30   60   90
2020-05-20    30   60   90
```

I tried to apply groupby after resampling (e.g. `dataframe.resample("2D").grouby("Group")`), but it raises a TypeError ("'TimeGrouper' object is not callable")

What could be a way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

Output of `dataframe.groupby(["Time","Group"]).mean()` :

```
                  Col1  Col2  Col3
Time       Group
2020-05-18 A        10    20    30
           B        10    20    30
           C        10    20    30
2020-05-19 A        10    20    30
           B        10    20    30
           C        10    20    30
2020-05-20 A        10    20    30
           B        10    20    30
           C        10    20    30
2020-05-21 A        10    20    30
           B        10    20    30
           C        10    20    30
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Can you add output after `gruopby` and before `resample` from sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with aggregate `mean`:

```
print (dataframe.groupby(['Group',pd.Grouper(freq='2D', key='Time')]).mean())
                  Col1  Col2  Col3
Group Time                        
A     2020-05-18    10    20    30
      2020-05-20    10    20    30
B     2020-05-18    10    20    30
      2020-05-20    10    20    30
C     2020-05-18    10    20    30
      2020-05-20    10    20    30
```

And then `sum` by second level `Time`:

```
df = (
    dataframe
    .groupby(['Group', pd.Grouper(freq='2D', key='Time')])
    .mean()
    .sum(level=1)
)

print (df)
            Col1  Col2  Col3
Time                        
2020-05-18    30    60    90
2020-05-20    30    60    90
```

Comment: By applying this code, I get the first result (rows [60, 120, 180]), which is the wrong one. The desired output is the last one. The problem with this code is that the first instruction `df.groupby(["Time","Group"]).mean()` averages according to Group in that precise time, but I need to average within a given time bin. So for example, if Group "A" occurs at 18/05/2020 and also at 19/05/2020, it needs to be averaged together (since my time bin is 2 days). But this first instruction will average the Group "A" in two days separately.

Comment: @Marvin - Hard test if data re in pictures - [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I added now the code to my question to generate the sample dataframe.

Comment: Thanks, it works! After my last question update, since I set "Time" as index, the parameter "key" in your solution should just be changed into "level", so it works as you described.